# Loading a popup using ajax

Tags: java, jquery, spring, xt

I have a jsp page which should load a popup using ajax. The content of the page is determined by form filled by user.

Something like this:

javascript:

```
ajax('getPage.action', 'content_id', 'form_id');
```

foo.jsp:

```
<div id="content_id"></div>

<form id="form_id">
 ...
</form>
```

java/spring:

```
@RequestMapping("getPage.action")
MyController extends AbstractCommandController {
  RealDto dto = (RealDto)command;
  ...
  return new ModelAndView("foo", data);
}
```

The most difficult part for me is how to send the form data easily as an ajax call. Can I use jQuery here? The form changes dynamically so it would be quite bothersome to list all the fields of the form.

Would it help to use Springs XT (which I never have)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can use [serialize](http://docs.jquery.com/Ajax/serialize) to trivially convert the form to send the data.

```
$("#form1").submit(function() {
    $.get("/desiredURL", $("#form1").serialize(), function(response) {
        // send response data to a popup
    }
}
```

You can use [get](http://docs.jquery.com/Ajax/jQuery.get#urldatacallbacktype) or [post](http://docs.jquery.com/Ajax/jQuery.post#urldatacallbacktype) to send the data.

For the popup I like [facebox](https://github.com/defunkt/facebox), but there's loads of choices.

Answer (score 2):

[jQuery form plug-in](http://malsup.com/jquery/form) can help you easily transform a regular form to an Ajax one. You only need a single line of code:

```
$("#myform").ajaxForm(
   {beforeSubmit: validate, success: showPopup} );
```

Comment: Yes, but with the form plug-in (especially together with validation plug-in) you convert a regular form to an AJAX one with a single line of code.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about jQuery, but for prototype this is easy:

```
new Ajax.Request('getPage.action', {
    parameters: $('form_id').serialize(true),
    onSuccess: someMethod
);
```

Check out the [Prototype API docs](http://www.prototypejs.org/api/).

This page has the same information for jQuery: http://docs.jquery.com/Ajax